# Is there a way to create an SQL "alias"?

Tags: mysql

If there is a complicated query that I want to perform multiple times, is there a way to store it as an "alias"? For example, store:

```
SELECT 
    table_schema "Data Base Name", 
    SUM( data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024 "Data Base Size in MB" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
GROUP BY table_schema ;
```

as

```
GET_DB_SIZES
```

Is something like that possible???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, create a `VIEW`:

```
CREATE VIEW GET_DB_SIZES AS <your query>;
```

Then you can:

```
SELECT * FROM GET_DB_SIZES;
```

Answer (score -1):

One option is to put resultset in a temporary table and use it further

Comment: Putting the result in a temporary table would be contrary to what the OP is trying to achieve. There is no guarantee for the results to be identical in his scenario - which is what putting in a temporary table will do