# Is there an easy way to create a command alias in mysql?

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface, alias

This question is similar to what I'm asking:
[Is there a way to create an SQL "alias"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318105/is-there-a-way-to-create-an-sql-alias)

But not quite the same - I'm learning mysql and am going to be running the select command a lot as I screw with different commands.  Is there a way I can alias something like:

select * from testdb

to

ls

Or something equally similar?  Ideally, I'd be able to alias "select * from" to something like "show" and then just type "show testdb".

Comment: I've searched for such a functionality, but AFAIK it's not possible with the standard mysql client.

Answer (score 9):

Three ideas come to mind:

1. a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/call.html), so you'd end up doing "call
   show('testdb')"
2. a [shell alias](http://www.ss64.com/bash/alias.html), so you run "show testdb" have it map to
   "mysql -e 'select * from testdb'"
3. suck it up and type the command.

Answer (score 1):

using alias with function can help you pass parameter to a alias like 
example query = `select * from testdb where param = 'test param'` 
 created alias = `sftb test param` 
 to create such alias you can write something like this in your bashrc file.
 `alias sftb='function sftb(){ mysql -e "select * from testdb where param = '$1'"; };sftb'`