# procedure/alias [a portion of] a somewhat long MySQL command?

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface, alias

### Not an "alias" but similar...

I'm working with an incomplete MySQL database, adding repetitive manual updates from an external reference. It's slow going, and I'm hoping to streamline a SELECT I've used dozens of times so far. I have a couple thousand of these ahead of me.

I've seen advice for creating PROCEDURES, but since I'm trying to "alias" a partial query, I may be asking the wrong question.

I want to condense this:

```
SELECT book, fulltitle, author, num, lastread, category FROM books
```

...to something like this:

```
sBk
```

So I type `sBk WHERE book="success";` and MySQL executes:

```
SELECT book, fulltitle, author, num, lastread, category FROM books WHERE book="success";
```

---

### consistency, R.I.P.

In my data, most authors are undefined--and my task is to fix that.  So I search my reference materials for the books by this author and then update the records.

Some books are named predictably, e.g. john1, john2, john3...  Others are not, e.g. jrs2, smithj9, fourteen1, AllYourBase, etc.  As a result, the commands often look like this:

```
SELECT book, fulltitle, author, num, lastread, group FROM books WHERE book like \
  "artp1%" OR book LIKE "aod%" OR book LIKE "fatal%" OR book LIKE "outside%" OR \
  book LIKE "geo-cache%" OR book LIKE "frostbite" OR book LIKE "quickb3%" OR book \
  LIKE "instantcof%" OR book = "sevenmile" OR book = "uberfast";
```

So I hit up arrow, remove the first portion, and type `author=` to get this:

```
UPDATE books SET author="John Smith" WHERE book LIKE (everything above)";
```

The lookups and book/author associations are manual, and I can't change that.  But there's gotta be a smarter way to execute these data updates once I get a SELECT statement that matches all the correct books.

---

### What I've tried - and caveats

- The `books` table has several dozen columns, or I'd simply `select *`.
- I could copy/paste from the prior select, but I'm sloppy with a mouse, making it just as slow as riding the delete key.
- It would be neat if MySQL has a function that's basically "act on the immediately previous select.  But if such a function exists, I've been unable to search the correct terminology to find it.

I tried [creating a procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16745734/5880274) but I couldn't get it to accept a partial command--and the error wasn't very descriptive--is there a way to correct what I'm doing here?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sBk()  BEGIN SELECT book, fulltitle, author, num, lastread, category from books END;

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that \
  corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

It's easy while matching a single book: hit up arrow to the previous UPDATE command, edit, move on. However, many of these commands' length and complexity pretty much kills the advantage of simply [UpArrow] to the previous statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your syntax error is that you didn't set a `DELIMITER`, and your procedure contains a `BEGIN...END` block. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html for details on this.

After you define the stored procedure, you can call it like this:

```
mysql> CALL sBk();
```

But that's the only way you can call it. You can't add a WHERE clause to a CALL statement. It's not an alias for the query.

You might consider a [VIEW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html) instead of a procedure.

As for your difficulty using up-arrow to edit the previous statement, you might like to use the `edit` or `\e` command in the mysql client, instead of up-arrow. This command opens a text editor such as `vi` (or whatever your `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` environment variable names). This gives you a lot more control over how you edit the SQL statement.

Comment: Welp, I clearly skimmed the PROCEDURE page yesterday. I really like the Vim option, but my client doesn't agree with [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-editing-code.html) that my new command will be displayed after editing--and I'm a bit too nervous to type ";" and execute a command I can't see. The view has some slight limitations with the "frozen in time" characteristic, but it's better than what I was doing. Thanks Bill!  My carpal tunnel doctor may not appreciate you...but I do!

Comment: Copy and paste is also a useful tool... :-)

Comment: I should amend my prior comment: The documentation's phrase "frozen in time" must apply only to adding columns and not updating data... so the VIEW is working splendidly for me.  And yes, C/P is handy--but I get clumsy with the mouse and prefer to keep my hands on the keyboard

Comment: (not seeking further help, btw, just offering supplemental info) I couldn't get the Vim option to work for me, because I couldn't figure out how to PREpend new commands--and since the MySQL console remembered the previous command but didn't *display* it... I was entering commands like `WHERE book="success"; UPDATE books SET author="John Smith";`  And of course those don't work very well.  :,)  Thanks again Bill!

Comment: Another solution I have used for repetitive work like the updates you describe is to write a short script in Python or whatever my current favorite language is. Just a loop, a prompt for a few values, and then execute an SQL statement using those values as parameters.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Good idea.  I considered a bash script (or aliases), but the complexity in compiling my "attack" command is made worse by some names being inconsistent in the first place.  I didn't want my question to get too long--not that I ever succeed at brevity anyway--so I omitted that part.  The VIEW is working pretty well.  I think I'm good with it.  Thanks again!